# integer from mysql always returns 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code that pulls data from a mysql db everything is pulling great, dates, variables, etc. The problem I have is the only integer is returning 0 every time.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$fufilled = "1";
$flag = $row['flag'];
$shopnumb = $row['Shopnumb'];
$shoptype = $row['Shop_type'];
...
```

`$shoptype` and `$shopnumb` both return correct content however $flag returns 0 every time even though the database has 1,1,1,1,0 for the 5 rows

```
CREATE TABLE `Shop_data` (
 `Shopnumb` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'shop id number',
 `flag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1=unread 0=read',
 `CID` int(15) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Client this shop belongs to',
 `SID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'identifys which survey to use',
 `comp_date` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Completion Date',
 `sched_date` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Scheduled shop date',
 `shop_comp` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'shopper submitted report',
 `edit_comp` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Report has been edited',
 `return_shop` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'return report to shopper for editing',
 `report_comp` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'report ready for client',
 `Shop_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Shoploc` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `shop_cost` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Normal or adjusted cost of shop',
 `shop_reimb` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shopper reimburstment cost',
 `shop_pay` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Total cost',
 `shopper_assign` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Identifys which shopper assigned',
 PRIMARY KEY (`Shopnumb`),
 UNIQUE KEY `Shopnumb` (`Shopnumb`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2252 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

my query

```
SELECT * FROM Shop_data WHERE CID='".$_SESSION['CID']."' AND report_comp='1' AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), comp_date) <".$lengthoftime." ORDER BY comp_date DESC;
```

like I said everything returns great except flag

if statement

```
        if ($flag = '0') {
            echo "<td align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;<img align=\"middle\" src=\"/images/flag.png\">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>";
        }
```

fixed
                if ($flag == '0') {

Comment: You need to give more information - `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable;`, the query you're running and the result from running that query in the mysql client would be a good start...

Comment: Also confirm it returns "0" and not "NULL", and confirm that the index is in the array (isset($row['flag'])). All would display "0" when converted to an integer, but are different and give a different clue as to what's wrong.

Comment: Next debug, "print_r($row);" as this shows the actual row data. If that's 0, then it's 0 in the database. If it's "1" in the array, then you're changing it to "0" somewhere else.

Comment: ok I think I have worked it down to being a problem with my if statement - print_R($flag) right before the if statement and right after the if statement are both returning correct values however the if statement is executing everything as 0
if statement in above

Comment: problem solved failed to have ==
I appreciate all the help

Comment: Equality is not the same as assignment! `$flag ==`, not `$flag =`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
if ($flag = '0') {
```

is assignment, and will *always* be TRUE (it evaluates to the value assigned, which is a string). You need:

```
if( ! intval($flag)) {
```